# Matter Devices are showing offline in Google Home APP after commissioning the device

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I created and added a matter device with test VID and PID in the google developer console in order to commission the device with Google Home App (GHA). I was able to commission the matter device successfully with GHA. Post commissioning process, the device shows offline in GHA.  Any thoughts on why the device is showing offline?

[Matter device details in Google Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxMWR.png)

I am expecting the device should be online in GHA and shall allow control of the device

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] to add a transcription of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: I'm running into same issue. I assume it's because I don't have a "Matter-enabled Google hub". (https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/13127223?hl=en)
Could this be the case for you as well?
Btw. I don't understand the technical reasons why a Google hub is needed. I though Matter does not need a hub.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a list of supported devices and development flows in the [developer documentation.](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/supported-devices) Please make sure that the systems you use are compatible (ideally with a Google Home Hub 2nd Gen), and the device you develop functions correctly. Once you verify the systems, if the issue still persists, please open up a ticket in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) listing the type and version numbers for your Hub and GHA.